# Permissions specific to a microservice

Tags: architecture, microservices, domain-driven-design

What is the best practice regarding the permissions specific to a microservice?

Imagine a system with several employees and several products

Each employees is assigned to some of products with a role(for that product):

- Employee-A | Product-A | can-view
- Employee-B | Product-A | can-order

...

- Employee-A | Product-B | can-order

...

Does these information belong to Product and Order microservices (denormalized), or it belongs to user claims.

Comment: I think the key here is to know what we are talking about. Are we talking about permissions of a user, permissions of an employee, or permissions of a product? By following the language spoken, you should be able to pick the most reasonable place to put them. Remember, no way of modeling is the best, some are just more useful to your case.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions that depend on the data that is going to be specific to a Bounded Context/Microservice would not be part of your typical Identity and Access Management (IAM) since on the IAM level you are dealing with permissions->roles->users.

It is not inconceivable to use a generic permission in your IAM to represent data specific to your BC but that is going to be a design decision.  For instance, I like to use a URI to represent a permission so I would have something like `bounded-context://feature/action` or some such.  You could then, for example, have `bounded-context://data-id` for a unique identifier.  For something like an identity field you may have `bounded-context://source/data-id`.  It may be unwieldy working with ids; although that may be mitigated by building a front-end that manages these.  Having too many permissions in and of itself may also not be ideal but again, it is going to be a design decision.

The other alternative is to manage the data access in the BC itself although that means building an access management system specific to the BC... a generic solution may be better for this but may still "live" in the BC space rather than the IAM space which is probably enterprise-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Role Based Access Control ([RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)).

Employees (subjects) have roles, which are associated with a set of permissions, products (entities) have permission-requirements for reading/editing.

Example: John has the ProductA-sales role, which contains the ProductA_Reader permission.   Product A has the requirement for ProductA_Reader permission.

This is a little redundant if you don't actually have roles, and each combination is unique...  at which point I'd skip the "role" concept and just have a table with userId->Permission mappings.  But most problem-spaces have pre-defined roles which group those and allow them to be reused.

Regardless, products have permssion-requirements, users have the list of permissions, the Product service will need to check the user's list of permissions before allowing the activity to proceed.